# How to stay logged in after page refresh with react native web?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a react native web expo app. And a user can login and browse to the pages. And everything untill this point works. But if a user refresh a page the user will be logged out en redirected to the login page.

And I looked in the dev tools section. And there I see that after page refresh the token has been deleted in the network section.

I have authentication service component and a authentication context component:

For the service login:

```
export const loginRequest = async (email, password) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/api/user/token/`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: email,
                password: password,
            }),
        });

        const data = await response.json();

        if (response.ok) {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem("Token", data.token);

            return true;
        } else {
            throw new Error(data.token);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        error, "email en of wachtwoord is niet goed ingevuld";
    }
};
```

and for the login context:

```
import {
    AccountRequest,
    AccountUpdateRequest,
    loginRequest,
    logoutRequest,
    registerRequest,
} from "./authentication.service";
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

    const onLogin = (email, password) => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        loginRequest(email, password)
            .then((u) => {
                setUser(u);

                setIsLoading(false);
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                setIsLoading(false);
                setError(e.toString());
            });
    };

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider
            value={{
                isAuthenticated: !!user,
                isLoading,
                error,
                user,
                onLogin,
                onRegister,
                onLogout,
                handleValidEmail,
                handleValidPassword,
                UserProfileRequest,
                UpdateUserProfileRequest,
            }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

And I am running the app on url: `http://localhost:19006/`

Question: how to persist the token after page refresh?

Comment: Somebody any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `useEffect` hook to restore the state. Something like this:

```
const [data, setData] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
  const getData = async () => {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('my-key');
    setData(value);
  };
  getData();
}, []);
...

return (
  <DataContext.Provider value={data}>
   ...
  </DataContext.Provider>
);
```